# Shortcut to send a couple of slides from a presentation

Tags: email, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Many a times I have to send specific slides out of a powerpoint presentation, via email.

I follow a manual process of selecting the slides, copying them, opening a new presentation and finally pasting the slides in the new presentation and save it. Then I attach the new presentation to an email.

I was wondering if there was a easier way to do this, especially for instances where a single slide is to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you can do this:

**A)** Save-As (rename file to be sent). Delete unwanted slides. File->Send to recipeient as (attachment, pdf, etc). No copy and paste needed.

or

**B)** Directly from your working PPT, select the slides you want to send by pressing Ctrl+"each slide"; by doing this you can select slides 1 and 3 say. 
Then select **File->Send To->Mail Recipient as Adobe PDF**. You will then be prompted to save a PDF file, but first open **"Options" -> Slide Range -> radio button 'selected slides'**. Save the file. Then PPT will create an adobe attachment and attach it to your PC's mail automatically. All you have to do then is to send the mail with recipient.